# Which eye of dajjal is blind, right or left?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, contradiction, dajjal

In the first it says

> SAHIH MUSLIM BOOK 41, HADITH NUMBER 7005. Chapter : Account of the
> Dajjal and his features and what would be along with.
>
> Ibn Umar reported that Allah’s Messenger (may peace be upon him). made
> a mention of Dajjil in the presence of the people and said: Allah is
> not one-eyed and behold that Dajjal is blind of the **right** eye and his
> eye would be like a floating grape
>
> https://sunnah.com/muslim:169e

But the second haidth it says:

> SAHIH MUSLIM BOOK 41, HADITH NUMBER 7010.
>
> Chapter : Account of the Dajjal and his features and what would be
> along with.
>
> Hudhaifa reported that Allah’s Messenger (may peace be upon him) said:
> Dajjal is blind of **left** eye with thick hair and there would be a
> garden and fire with him and his fire would be a garden and his garden
> would be fire. Which one is correct I'm confused and isn't this an
> contradiction?
>
> https://sunnah.com/muslim:2934a

Comment: Links to the ahadith in question: https://sunnah.com/muslim:169e https://sunnah.com/muslim:2934a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ahadith have different chains so it is possible that some transmitters made a mistake and mixed up left with right or vice versa. Some scholars have considered the report from Ibn Umar about the right eye to be more likely to be correct as it has a stronger chain fulfilling the conditions of [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7123) as well as that of Muslim.

However it is also possible that both his eyes are defective with somewhat different problems - أعور means defective not necessarily the defect of blindness.

Ref:

> ومثله لمسلم من حديث حذيفة، وهذا بخلاف قوله في حديث الباب: أعور العين اليمنى. وقد اتفقا عليه من حديث ابن عمر، فيكون أرجح، وإلى ذلك أشار ابن عبد البر لكن جمع بينهما القاضي عياض فقال: تصحح الروايتان معا بأن تكون المطموسة والممسوحة هي العوراء الطافئة بالهمز أي التي ذهب ضوؤها، وهي العين اليمنى كما في حديث ابن عمر، وتكون الجاحظة التي كأنها كوكب وكأنها نخاعة في حائط هي الطافية بلا همز وهي العين اليسرى كما جاء في الرواية الأخرى، وعلى هذا فهو أعور العين اليمنى واليسرى معا فكل واحدة منهما عوراء أي معيبة، فإن الأعور من كل شيء المعيب، وكلا عيني الدجال معيبة
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/7528#p1)</sup>

Comment: Allah swt is the most merciful and most forgiving may Allah swt guide to Islam and forgive all you sins make you go jannat al firadus highest rank of heaven and you family and friends as well may Allah swt guide them both and you aswell Ameen❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction, both hadiths taken together give you the dual perspective of the viewer,  if you were face-to-face with Dajjal then his left eye would appear blind to you, if you were facing his back or he is facing your back then his right eye would appear blind to you (regardless of him facing a reflective surface like a mirror or not), either way Dajjal is always blind in one-eye thus why أَعْوَر (blind/defect one-eyed) and not أَعْمى (blind/defective both eyes) is used, otherwise he could easily negate the charge that he is indeed Dajjal had only one perspective of his defective eye been given by simply using your vantage point of his eye as proof. This dual perspective is applied in optical illusions, and also in commercial gadgets like phones with front-facing and back-facing camera pending on which camera you use, your eye-perspective changes from left to right or vice versa, obviously there is more to this but Allah knows best.

Comment: But it doesn't say anything about the pov of the people tho akhi

Comment: Where does it say it doesn't say that?

Answer (score -2):

May be he is blind in both eyes

> Have they not travelled throughout the land so their hearts may
> reason, and their ears may listen? **Indeed, it is not the eyes that are
> blind, but it is the hearts in the chests that grow blind.** Quran 22:46